# Configuring insecure (http) private docker registry with halyard in spinnaker

Tags: docker, docker-registry, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm able to configure public docker hub registry using below halyard command, however while trying to use the same command to configure a privately hosted docker registry (insecure) I'm facing the below error.

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add private-docker-registry 
    --address <privateIP>:5000 
    --repositories <privateIP>:5000/<imagename> 
    --username <user> 
    --password


+ Get current deployment
  Success
- Add the private-docker-registry account
  Failure
Problems in
  default.provider.dockerRegistry.private-docker-registry:
! ERROR Unable to reach repository: Unrecognized SSL message,
  plaintext connection?.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag
--insecure-registry=true